# Reliable strtotime() result for different languages

Tags: php, datetime, joomla, php4

There was always a strange bug in Joomla when adding new article with back-end displayed with a language other than English (for me it's Russian). The field "Finish Publishing" started to be current date instead of "Never" equivalent in Russian.

For a site in php4 finally found that strtotime function returns different results for arbitrary words. For "Never" it always -1 and joomla relies on this result in the JDate implementation. But in other case it sometimes returns a valid date. For russian translation of Never (Никогда) it is the case, but also for single "N" it is the case, so if one decided to change the string to some other he or she would face the same issue.

So the code below

```
    <?php
      echo "Res:".strtotime("N")."<br>";
      echo "Res:".strtotime("Nev")."<br>";
      echo "Res:".strtotime("Neve")."<br>";
      echo "Res:".strtotime("Never")."<br>";
    ?>
```

Outputs:

```
    Res:1271120400
    Res:-1
    Res:-1
    Res:-1
```

So what are the solutions would be in this case? I would like not to write language-specific date.php handler, but to modify date method of JDate class, but what are language-neutral changes would be in order to detect invalid string.

Thank you

Comment: what is the question in short? What result you want to get? The word "Never" doesn't seem like any sensible datetime value.

Comment: Ok, I wonder why other non-sensible values like Never in russian is translated to a sensible date, and not only russian, single "N" also. I suppose due to some default conversion appearing

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different aproach.
Why don't you try just to add a new language variable `$example="-1"` to your language files and replace the existing variable ("Никогда" output) with `$example` so you can simply get the same functionallity.